# Sqlite Prepare Statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have 12 columns in my table. In which last two columns are added newly. I use sqlite3 database. Database is created and query is executed correctly if I use where clause for any other columns other than lastly created two new columns. The last two columns return NULL string which makes the app crash throwing **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** *+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'****

When the query is executed in SQL Manager I could retrieve last two columns. I suppose somewhere something is wrong in my prepare statement.

```
    NSString *query = @"select * from tableName where lastColumn = 'Value'";
    const char *sqlStatement = [query UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
// Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    }
```

Please Help me on this. I totally have no clue where the last two columns have gone.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing NULL to stringWithUTF8String: method, which is not allowed. You should check the value you get from sqlite before instantiating NSString object.

```
const char *ctext = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
if (ctext) {
    text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ctext];
}
```

When you added new columns, values for this columns in all existing rows were set to NULL.

Comment: But, it is not going into prepare statement loop to check whether the string is NULL or not. You want me to execute this before prepare statement ? How do I loop through the database if I m not doing it in prepare statement ?

Comment: The error you get is not related with prepare statement at all. Your error is about NSString, and sqlite is just plain C api, it doesn't allocate NSStrings

Comment: If I use any one of last two columns as my value for WHERE clause, it doesn't even go into prepare statement loop. If I use any other column value other than last two columns as my WHERE clause value, it goes inside the prepare statement loop and app crashes throwing NSInvalidArguementException when I try to retrieve last two column values. This is my problem. Sorry for not giving you clear idea before..